# Chemical Test for tin

Tags: experimental-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, elements

How can I distinguish whether a metal that I have is tin ($\ce{Sn}$)? I am specifically looking for a chemical reaction that will happen only with tin and not with other metals such as $\ce{Al,~Cu,~Fe,~\ldots}$. Do such reactions exist? What are they?

Comment: I think this question would be incomplete without mentioning what metals the sample could be made of, i.e. all of the metals.

Comment: @inɒzɘmɒЯ.A.M It could be made of: $\ce{Al,~Ti,~V,~Fe,~Co,~Ni,~Cu,~Zn,~Sn}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beside determining the volumic density (tin: 7.31 g/ccm, aluminum: 2.7 g/ccm, etc. pp) and as asked here on chemistry SE, there is a quick pre-test.  In German it is known as "Leuchtprobe", literally "illumination probe".  Be reminded to protect yourself properly (safety googles, fume hood, gloves).

In a first instance, you have to reduce the tin compound.  For this, a little of your solid under investigation is finely mixed together with some grains of zinc (Zn). In a porcelain dish, to this mixuture is added 5 mL of 20 m% aqueous HCl.  Await this reaction ceased.  Zn will produce hydrogen, and because it is freshly created (*statu nascendi*), it is of superiour reducing power compared to bottled hydrogen gas, and the solution is cooled to room temperature.

Then dip a cool test tube, partially filled with cold water, into this solution.  While still wetted by the solution, rapidly  place the test tube into the upper part of the non-luminous flame of a Bunsen burner.  Blue fluorescence is an almost specific evidence for tin (caused by $\ce{SnCl2}$, and stannanes), already at low concentrations.

Presence of arsenic may hamper this fluorescence.  Niob-compounds yield some similar fluorescence, too.  Beside using tin-free chemicals and equipment to be used -- and prior to the test of your unknown -- do at least once the test *in known absence* of tin, and once with a sample *with tin* to learn how to discern the two instances.

Comment: One can better detect the fluroescence by adding potassium permanganate into the test tube to create a dark background. (Or so I heard; I let others do that test in the ion lottery practical course.)

Comment: I agree with this comment; a test tube partially filled with a cold aqueous potassium permanganate solution increases the contrast compared to a test tube simply filled with blank water. Own practical experience in the lab (not only during the initial (in)organic Marcha analítica separation process

Comment: but as TA, too) that a test tube hold too long unshaken eventually leads to a bumping solution, including a stain on cloth and skin.

Comment: Is there any other analytical method to recognize tin?

Comment: My initial answer assumed you look for a qualitative test with as little as possible techniqual equipment and chemicals.  To go further depends on the sample matrix and often, there are reliable procedures to do this.  The U.S. american NIST, for example, developped digestion standards how to proceed properly, like this more senior reference (http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/21/jresv21n1p95_A1b.pdf).   Atomic absorption spectroscopy (AAS) would represent an alternative (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_absorption_spectroscopy), tin being listed in the table "GFAA method development".

Comment: By coincidence, AAS was a recent answered question, too: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/30892/atomizers-in-aas

Comment: Don't look at the fluorescence too long, because the water in the tube locally overheats within ten seconds: splash!

Comment: @Karl And safety glasses/goggles.  And chemically speaking, to perform the test at least once with a blank (no tin) and once with presence of tin as each measurement is *a comparison* against a reference. The illumination in the lab (fluorescent tube / LED lumiophore / day light) can influence how well it is seen, too.

Comment: We always put some KMnO4 into the tube with cold water, so it's practically black. Makes it much easier to see the fluorescense. And gives brown stains everywhere in case of spillage. And yea, safety glasses! ;)